# Force ADBannerView to rotate (Not "orientation" but actual transform)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this is NOT a how do I force orientation of my app question as it might look like.

My problem is probably very simple, but it is hard to describe it so here goes.

I am trying to implement iAd to my iphone game. This is not a problem, it was a 10 minute fix, just follow tutorials on the web. However, my game was programmed by a contractor since I can't program very well and he made the game translated to landscape orientation instead of oriented to landscape. This has leads to some problems for me when trying to rotate the ads correctly.

Bottom line is that CGRect which is what iAd uses does simply not have the transform function so no matter what I do the ads are standing on their side. This is quite natural since the app doesn't know that the game is meant to be played in landscape.

After a full day of research it seems that I need to put my iAd CGRect in a different view and rotate that view using the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. My really big problem is that I am not good enough at Objective-C to actually do that.

So can you help me how I should be able to apply transform to my ad?

Code below compiles and shows the ad but standing on its side (when holding the game in landscape)

```
//iAD starts
// lower right:-136, 295, 320, 32    lower left:-136, 135, 320, 32   upper right:136, 295, 320, 32
// *Controller becomes a UIViewController
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 32);
//controller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0); // turn 180 degrees
NSLog(@"*controller");  


    //adView becomes a CGRectZero called adView
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
//adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, 0);
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape,ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait,nil];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
[self.view addSubview:adView];


adView.delegate=self;

//self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

// iAD ends
```

Best regards
Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should rotate as you are asking.
This code has worked for me in my iAd apps: Directly from Apple Source Code

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface TextViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    UIView *contentView;
    ADBannerView *banner;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import ".h"

@interface TextViewController()

// Layout the Ad Banner and Content View to match the current orientation.
// The ADBannerView always animates its changes, so generally you should
// pass YES for animated, but it makes sense to pass NO in certain circumstances
// such as inside of -viewDidLoad.
-(void)layoutForCurrentOrientation:(BOOL)animated;

// A simple method that creates an ADBannerView
// Useful if you need to create the banner view in code
// such as when designing a universal binary for iPad
-(void)createADBannerView;

@end

@implementation TextViewController

@synthesize contentView, banner;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // If the banner wasn't included in the nib, create one.
    if(banner == nil)
    {
        [self createADBannerView];
    }
    [self layoutForCurrentOrientation:NO];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self layoutForCurrentOrientation:NO];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [self layoutForCurrentOrientation:YES];
}

-(void)createADBannerView{
    // --- WARNING ---
    // If you are planning on creating banner views at runtime in order to support iOS targets that don't support the iAd framework
    // then you will need to modify this method to do runtime checks for the symbols provided by the iAd framework
    // and you will need to weaklink iAd.framework in your project's target settings.
    // See the iPad Programming Guide, Creating a Universal Application for more information.
    // http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/general/conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
    // --- WARNING ---

    // Depending on our orientation when this method is called, we set our initial content size.
    // If you only support portrait or landscape orientations, then you can remove this check and
    // select either ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait (if portrait only) or ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape (if landscape only).
    NSString *contentSize;
    if (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil)
    {
        contentSize = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }
    else
    {
        // user the older sizes 
        contentSize = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
    }

    // Calculate the intial location for the banner.
    // We want this banner to be at the bottom of the view controller, but placed
    // offscreen to ensure that the user won't see the banner until its ready.
    // We'll be informed when we have an ad to show because -bannerViewDidLoadAd: will be called.
    CGRect frame;
    frame.size = [ADBannerView sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:contentSize];
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0f, CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds));

    // Now to create and configure the banner view
    ADBannerView *bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    // Set the delegate to self, so that we are notified of ad responses.
    bannerView.delegate = self;
    // Set the autoresizing mask so that the banner is pinned to the bottom
    bannerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    // Since we support all orientations in this view controller, support portrait and landscape content sizes.
    // If you only supported landscape or portrait, you could remove the other from this set.

    bannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil) ?
        [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil] : 
        [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32, nil];

    // At this point the ad banner is now be visible and looking for an ad.
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];
    self.banner = bannerView;
    [bannerView release];
}

-(void)layoutForCurrentOrientation:(BOOL)animated{
    CGFloat animationDuration = animated ? 0.2f : 0.0f;
    // by default content consumes the entire view area
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    // the banner still needs to be adjusted further, but this is a reasonable starting point
    // the y value will need to be adjusted by the banner height to get the final position
    CGPoint bannerOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(contentFrame),CGRectGetMaxY(contentFrame));
    CGFloat bannerHeight = 0.0f;

    // First, setup the banner's content size and adjustment based on the current orientation
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
        banner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape != nil) ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
    else
        banner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil) ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50; 
    bannerHeight = banner.bounds.size.height; 

    // Depending on if the banner has been loaded, we adjust the content frame and banner location
    // to accomodate the ad being on or off screen.
    // This layout is for an ad at the bottom of the view.
    if(banner.bannerLoaded)
    {
        contentFrame.size.height -= bannerHeight;
        bannerOrigin.y -= bannerHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        bannerOrigin.y += bannerHeight;
    }

    // And finally animate the changes, running layout for the content view if required.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                 animations:^{
                     contentView.frame = contentFrame;
                     [contentView layoutIfNeeded];
                     banner.frame = CGRectMake(bannerOrigin.x, bannerOrigin.y, banner.frame.size.width, banner.frame.size.height);
                 }];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload{
    self.contentView = nil;
    banner.delegate = nil;
    self.banner = nil;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [contentView release]; contentView = nil;
    banner.delegate = nil;
    [banner release]; banner = nil; 
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark ADBannerViewDelegate methods
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [self layoutForCurrentOrientation:YES];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [self layoutForCurrentOrientation:YES];
}

-(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave{
    return YES;
}

-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
}

@end
```

Comment: That is awesome! I will make sure to use this if/when I ity to integrate iads again. For now I went with mobfox which was easier for me to integrate. Thanks so much for helping though!

Answer (score 0):

If the game is rotated, why don't you stop the rotation of the game?

Comment: You don't understand, the assets and everything is made sideways so that it becomes right when you use the device in landscape. the code does not ever tell the device that it is in landscape.

Strictly speaking the game runs to the right but when you play it you play it upward like doodle jump, because you play in landscape. It's all fake and that's why I have so much problems.

Comment: So tell your view controller your in landscape, so the ADBannerView appears properly? Or am I not understanding. Mail me your code if you want more help: benjaminzamayo@gmail.com

Comment: I'll gladly mail you the code, but what do you need? It's a pretty big xcode project with tons of images and sounds, could I just send the viewController.m and .h?
Best regards

Comment: Are you using a xib? If so send that too.

Comment: Thanks alot for the offer! I managed to do the transform but now I have a different (even simpler!) problem. I'll post it here and link to it. 

Cheers!

Comment: Guys what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted by using a different ad SDK (mobfox) the rotation I wanted to do looks like this:

```
// MOBFOX Starts
// create the banner view just outside of the visible area
MobFoxBannerView *bannerView = [[MobFoxBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                CGRectMake(-800, self.view.bounds.size.height - 240, 320, 50)];
bannerView.delegate = self;  // triggers ad loading
//bannerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; // fill horizontally
bannerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0); 
//bannerView.refreshAnimation = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView];

NSLog(@"MobFox: Ad initated and placed offscreen");

//
```

The transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation was not accepted by the iAd stuff and since I am too weak on objective-c to force it to my will. This is what I did.

Thanks for offering to help!